# s3cmd version 2.1.0 not working with session token

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, ubuntu-18.04, s3cmd

i recently updated s3cmd version to 2.1.0. I want to use Temporary Security Credentials which comes with assume role. This is how my ~/.s3cfg file looks like -

```
[default]
access_key=XXXXXXXXX
secret_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
access_token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEL3//////////wEaDMk0T+yZCPMSV6H6sCKnAaG4EJ9fc5AlWsZxeZpkBpyuvHmylfbz8Ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am getting error :

```
ERROR: Access to bucket '92xxxxxxx-chef' was denied
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied): Access Denied
```

while passing keys (access_key, secret_key, access_token) along with command line it's working fine.

```
    ~# s3cmd ls s3://928xxxxxxxx-chef/ --access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXX --secret_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --
access_token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEL3//////////wEaDMk0T+yZCPMSV6H6sCKnAaG4EJ9fc5AlWsZxeZpkBpyuvHmylfbz8Ie5gRQiHrVFULW4bszAKejZShEXUxZKV0Zqj2J9qY8SlE8Fe6kZ+hgqyJAS4ydfKei4JxSK5xHblRrivKou3yyZgTXzWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

                       DIR   s3://9281xxxxxxxx-chef/git/
                       DIR   s3://9281xxxxxxxx-chef/xxxxxxx-validator/
2020-08-19 14:19      3601   s3://9281xxxxxxxx-chef/chef_init.rb
```

Comment: You shouldn't post secrets like the secret_key publicly

Comment: Works for me with s3cmd version 2.1.0+. Unless I supply the credentials on the command-line the way you described, I just get a warning: `WARNING: Could not refresh role`.